# Calculate single cashflow at maturity for a Total Return Inflation swap (zero coupon)

Tags: inflation

I'm a newbie to the world of swaps.

If I have a Total Return Inflation Swap (Receive CPI, Pay Fixed Zero Coupon)

Based on CPI Index starting level = [236](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/CPURNSA:IND)
Notional = 100,000
Term = 5 Years

How can I calculate the final payoff at maturity using a hypothetical future CPI level e.g. 300 ? Are there any excel and/or R examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ZC inflation swaps, the fixed side cash flow is
$$ N \big((1 + r)^T - 1\big), $$
where $N$ is the national amount, $r$ is the agreed upon ZC swap rate, and $T$ is the tenor of the swap.

The floating side cash flow is
$$ N\left( \frac{I(T)}{I_\text{base}} - 1 \right), $$
where $I_\text{base}$ is the base index level (reference index as of the effective date) and $I(T)$ is the reference index as of the termination date.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a source / link to these formulas for all types of swaps?

Comment: This open gamma one is the first thing that popped into my head... http://developers.opengamma.com/quantitative-research/Inflation-Instruments-OpenGamma.pdf  I think they have a bunch of references for other instruments too. Specifically for inflation swaps, there are a lot of really good sell-side research papers. Search for Lehman Brothers, Inflation Derivatives Explained, as an example.

Comment: In terms of valuation, how do I go about estimating the expectation of $I(T)$ for some date $t<T$ before I can observe the index fixing?

Comment: @KevinT These are inferred from quoted ZC inflation swaps, from which you'd construct an inflation swap curve.

Comment: Hi @Helin, many thanks for following up on this older thread. Setting up the curve now, and I was wondering about *interpolation*. Is it better practice to interpolate the CPI values, or to interpolate the zero-coupon rates (i.e., basically given quoted zero rates, is interpolation done before or after finding the corresponding index values)?

Comment: Hi @KevinT. You'd start by building out the curve (in index number terms) at annual intervals (1y, 2y, etc.) based on the zero coupon rates and you'll need to make some assumptions about trend inflation between large quoted intervals (e.g. if you only have 10y and 15y zero rates, you'd assume trend inflation is constant during 10-15y to get index numbers for 11y, 12y, etc.). To fill in the sub-annual points (i.e., 1y1m, 1y2m, etc.) you need a seasonality model. This process should give you the index values across the entire curve.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to swap calculations is understanding what your profit is. Profit is (what you receive - what you pay). You can use this to calculate swaps on interest rates, equity swaps, and so on.

What will you receive? You are receiving: CPI appreciation x Notional. (300/236 - 1) * 100,000 = 27,118.

What are you paying? You are paying the zero coupon rate. Let's say it is 10%, which is 10,000.

Final payoff to swap long at maturity = 27,118 - 10,000 = 17,118. You said "you have" the swap, so I assume you are the fixed rate payer.

In Excel, you could do something like this:
http://www.fincad.com/resources/resource-library/article/how-build-workbook-value-total-return-swap-floating-rate-loan

Modify for you specific swap.